# python importError name lru_cache

Tags: python, macos, import

While running the code below, I am getting the error that Python cannot import lru_cache. However, this happens with every import (math, etc...).  I've tried every single tutorial I can find on the internet to try to get this thing to work. I've reinstalled Python. Pip and homebrew are installed as well.

```
#!usr/bin
from functools import lru_cache
import math

fibonacci_cache = {}

@lru_cache(maxsize = 1000)
def fibonacci(n):

    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

for n in range(1, 501):
    print(n, ":", fibonacci(n))
```

The error:

```
Kapoyas-MacBook-Pro:bin Keaton$ python python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python.py", line 2, in <module>
from functools import lru_cache
ImportError: cannot import name lru_cache
```

Comment: [`lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html)  is in python3.  What version are you using?

Comment: Perhaps your default python interpreter is python2. Just check it.

Comment: how do i check. i googled it and all i find is people telling me how to edit the bash profile. Which honestly doesnt help me at all.

Comment: `...this happens with every import (math, etc...)` suggest you change your title to accurately reflect your problem.

Comment: Oh im using 2.7 apparently! how can i change that?

Comment: Type `python` in your terminal.  It will say the version after it loads.

Comment: 2.7 if you didnt catch the above comment

Comment: If you want to keep to use 2.7, try to install `functools32` and try `from functools32 import lru_cache`

Answer (score 3):

Due to version(python 2.7 or 3.x), as provided in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/backports.functools_lru_cache/) consider using:

```
try:
    from functools import lru_cache
except ImportError:
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. i needed that direct help! the answer was as simple as editing the bash profile.

for any one else thats not experienced and this is their first time trying these things. here is a full breakdown

step one: 
go to finder and click GO in the top bar. then click "go to folder"

step two:
type "~/.bash_profile" and click enter

step three:
add this line to  the end of the file "alias python='python3' "  save and exit

step four: run program again!